# Keep generating linker and library errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, googletest

I tried compiling/building the google test samples but I decided to try something simplifier instead when I couldn't get the samples to work. I found this video that details how to set up the unit tests and run them using google test (but from the command line instead): http://vimeo.com/53690756

However, assuming the source code is correctly implemented and I went to my project's properties and set the C/C++'s Additional Include Directories to the g-test-1.6.0 include directory and the Linker's Additional library directories to the same g-test-1.6.0 include directory. However, Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, I wrote gtestd.lib.

The only error I get is 101 error LNK1103: cannot open file 'gtestd.lib', I guess what I didn't get from the video is how they generated that static library file? When I ran the build using debug previously on another project, I was able to get a gtestd.lib file under Debug and I tried to include that file under the g-test-1.6.0 include directory but then I got 65 linker errors instead.

Essentially, what I'm asking is how to set up google test in Visual Studio 2010 without getting a library or linker error? Where do I get the proper version of gtest.lib or gtestd.lib and where should I place that library file so it's found?

Here are a few of the linker errors I'm receiving:

```
Warning 65  warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other  libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library  C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LINK  Testproject99
Warning 66  warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library   C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LINK  Testproject99
Error   64  error LNK2005: _vprintf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)   C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(vprintf.obj)  Testproject99
Error   59  error LNK2005: _strtol already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)    C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(strtol.obj)   Testproject99
Error   58  error LNK2005: _sprintf_s already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj)  Testproject99
Error   63  error LNK2005: _printf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)    C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(printf.obj)   Testproject99
Error   49  error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)   C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0.obj) Testproject99
Error   45  error LNK2005: _localeconv already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)    C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(lconv.obj)    Testproject99
Error   44  error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)    C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(fflush.obj)   Testproject99
Error   39  error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)  C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj)  Testproject99
Error   50  error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)   C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(winxfltr.obj) Testproject99
Error   62  error LNK2005: __vsnprintf_s already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)  C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(vsnprnc.obj)  Testproject99
Error   48  error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)   C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj)    Testproject99
Error   60  error LNK2005: __strtoui64 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)    C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(strtoq.obj)   Testproject99
Error   37  error LNK2005: __open_osfhandle already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)   C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(osfinfo.obj)  Testproject99
Error   47  error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj)    Testproject99
Error   57  error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)    C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)   Testproject99
Error   56  error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)    C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)   Testproject99

Error   29  error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_ctor(class std::_Locinfo *,char const *)" (?_Locinfo_ctor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@PBD@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)  C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) Testproject99
Error   23  error LNK2005: "public: class std::locale::facet * __thiscall std::locale::facet::_Decref(void)" (?_Decref@facet@locale@std@@QAEPAV123@XZ) already defined in gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)   Testproject99
Error   22  error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z) already defined in gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj)    C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)   Testproject99
Error   3   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > *)" (??0?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@PAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@@Z) already defined in gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj)  C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)   Testproject99
Error   32  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)    C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)   Testproject99
Error   31  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)   Testproject99
Error   18  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj)    C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)   Testproject99
Error   21  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)   Testproject99
Error   11  error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setp(char *,char *,char *)" (?setp@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD00@Z) already defined in gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj)   C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)   Testproject99
Error   8   error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setp(char *,char *)" (?setp@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEXPAD0@Z) already defined in gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj)   C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)   Testproject99
Error   27  error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Testproject99\libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) Testproject99
Error   67  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\Users\smorsi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Testproject99\Debug\Testproject99.exe Testproject99
```

I started over following Chemistpp's steps and When I added "_VARIADIC_MAX=10" to Preprocessor, I got these warnings (but no errors) when building the solutions.

```
Warning 108 warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\smorsi\Desktop\gtest-1.6.0\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md/Debug\gtest_unittest-md.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\smorsi\Desktop\gtest-1.6.0\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md\Debug\gtest_unittest.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  990 6   gtest_unittest-md
Warning 106 warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\smorsi\Desktop\gtest-1.6.0\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md/Debug\gtest_prod_test-md.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\smorsi\Desktop\gtest-1.6.0\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md\Debug\gtest_prod_test.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).    C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  990 6   gtest_prod_test-md
Warning 104 warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\smorsi\Desktop\gtest-1.6.0\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md/Debug\gtest_main-md.lib) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\smorsi\Desktop\gtest-1.6.0\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md\Debug\gtest_main-mdd.lib). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  1151    6   gtest_main-md
Warning 102 warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\smorsi\Desktop\gtest-1.6.0\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md/Debug\gtest-md.lib) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\smorsi\Desktop\gtest-1.6.0\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md\Debug\gtestd.lib). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).   C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  1151    6   gtest-md
Warning 109 warning MSB8012: TargetName(gtest_unittest-md) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (gtest_unittest). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  992 6   gtest_unittest-md
Warning 107 warning MSB8012: TargetName(gtest_prod_test-md) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (gtest_prod_test). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).    C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  992 6   gtest_prod_test-md
Warning 105 warning MSB8012: TargetName(gtest_main-md) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (gtest_main-mdd). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  1153    6   gtest_main-md
Warning 103 warning MSB8012: TargetName(gtest-md) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (gtestd). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).   C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  1153    6   gtest-md
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem.  It cannot find gtest.lib.  I just provided a [SSCCE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) to show this does work.  First read over the [gtest documentation](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Documentation) and note you will need to build the libraries from source.  When doing so, while using MSVC, you'll encounter errors because MSVC does not support something to do with [variadics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274588/c2977-stdtuple-too-many-template-arguments-msvc11)? I used [this solution](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=412) and will outline it here in spirit of not providing the answer via links.

Step 1: Download [gtest 1.6](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/downloads/list)

Step 2: Extract to directory, DIR.

Step 3: Navigate to DIR/msvc

Step 4: Double click gtest-md.sln and migrate if you need to.  You'll get some warnings.

Step 5: For **each** project in the solution, right click and add this to preprocessor definitions in C/C++. `_VARIADIC_MAX=10`

Step 6: Build Solutions.

Step 7: Navigate to `DIR/msvc/gtest-md/Debug/`  This folder has the gtestd.lib as well as gtest-main-mdd.lib file.  I took the entire contents of `Debug` pasted it in a new folder `DIR/lib`.

Step 8: Create a new blank sol and a new blank project.  Add a new blank .cpp.

Step 9: Goto `Project->Properties->vc++ directories`  Add `DIR/Include` under the additional include libraries and the `DIR/lib` under the additional library dependencies.

Step 10: Goto `Linker->Input` and under additional dependencies add `gtestd.lib`.

Step 11: Goto `C/C++->Preprocessor` and under preprocessor definitions add `_VARIADIC_MAX=10`

Step 12: In source add

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h> //Or wherever your header file seems to be

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I did and I have created a SSCCE for this library.  If you are not then you need to consider if you created the .lib incorrectly or haven't pointed msvc towards the right directory for the library.

Comment: Actually I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010( Visual C++ 2010). What you said about the .dll file could be what is wrong because I moved the lib file without the .dll.. EDIT: Just tried it but no luck. Same error.

Comment: Did you double check that your library directory is pointed at the library folder and not the include folder (if .h and .lib is in the same folder, then it's okay).  After adding the additional directories, you add the gtest.lib under linker->input->additional dependencies.  Then you put the .dll in the correct folder (by default I Think that is `C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\proj\proj`

Comment: yes I did exactly what you just said but I get the same error which is a bit strange.

Comment: EDIT: yes I did exactly what you just said however I get 65 errors on different kinds of linkers. The path to my gtestd.lib is C:~\Downloads\gtest-1.6.0\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\Testproject99\Debug\ .Problem is I don't see a .dll file inside that directory? And now, I'm getting LNK2005 errors and LNK4098 warnings

Comment: Please paste the error as so we can tract it down.   

`LNK2005: Cannot find blah`

Secondly, I will try to create an SSCCE with your library real fast with this lib.

Comment: Did you follow the build guide?
http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Setting_up_a_New_Test_Project

Comment: I edited my post to include the errors I'm receiving. Why do I need to add a preprocessor, _VARIADIC_MAX=10? I forgot that step. Also, I might have just built the library incorrectly. I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Something to do with std::tuple and requiring some variadic things.  I don't know 'why', I just know that was what google suggested me to do and it worked.

Comment: Ah I see. I got some build warnings when I added the preprocessor. See the last paragraph above.

Comment: Have you tried building the SSCCE? Did that warning come from building the solutions or from building your project that you've already tried to link?  If those aren't errors, then is your solution building?

Comment: Also, your example worked just fine. However, when it came to the other code. It didn't for some reason. I guess I'll try again.

Comment: Ok, it's good to know we're getting somewhere :)  I'll think about it some more.  Not sure why it is giving troubles for your other code.

Comment: I ran sample 1 from the sample documents and I got these two errors: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup c:\Users\smorsi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testproj00\testproj00\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) testproj00
Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals c:\users\smorsi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\testproj00\Debug\testproj00.exe 1 1 testproj00
Besides, that it seems fine.

Comment: I would also check to make sure your subsystem is set to console.  Linker->System->subsystem

Comment: Thanks I think I finally got it working :D Btw, I didn't change the system.

Answer (score 3):

I recently built gtest1.6 for Visual Studio 2010 and got it to work after having similar errors that you report.

I wish I had kept better track of what I did to fix it, but I am pretty sure it was just setting C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library to /MT for the gtest projects (gtest and gtest_main) and my own test project.  See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531941/how-to-setup-google-c-testing-framework-gtest-on-visual-studio-2005).

I did not change anything to do with variadics.

Comment: Those solutions were posted two years ago.  Are you using recent gtest and have you tried to link without adding the _variadics_max?

Comment: Thanks for your post. Actually, I realized if I just go to Debug -> Start Debugging, it works fine and I get the test results which is all I need. Thank you for linking me to that post.

Comment: @Chemistpp As I said, I am using gtest1.6.  I downloaded and built it about 3 weeks ago.  All I can say is that for the projects I have used it for (which are not many) it has worked without doing anything to variadic settings.

Comment: @A.E.Drew Sorry, missed that.  That's odd.  I tried to build it and found the variadic solution when I googled why my linking had failed.  Truly unexpected and maybe masking a different problem.

Comment: I'm having a hard time running my projects without getting linker errors all the time. Only one project is currently working.